# check box click event or change event is not working in angular js

Tags: angularjs

check box click event or change event is not working in angular js can anybody tell what is problem how to fix it

```
IN Html 
    <div class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" 
                  id="chkFinancial"  
                   data-ng-model ="finance" 
                   data-ng-click="checkChange();"/>   

                    <label >
                Test Checkbox

            </label>
            </div><br/>
```

In controller

```
    $scope.checkChange = function() {
/*if($scope.finance==true){
 $scope.finance=false;  
}
else {
 $scope.finance=true;   
}*/
alert($scope.finance);

};
```

Thanks

Comment: are you getting any console error ?

Comment: You code seems to be correct. please share more code. Create a fiddle please.

Comment: working http://plnkr.co/edit/U5bhbICI0xbzEZ5lyDqh?p=preview

Comment: @user386430 Have you added your controller to view using ng-controller? Better show your complete code in question